# Debug the source code in Eclipse when connected from Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tomcat

I have a tomcat server running a web application say, "A" which runs in  port 8080.

I have another tomcat server started inside eclipse, say "B" which runs in port 8181.

Now, in a particular point, A is calling some service in B. I would like to debug the "B" service which runs in eclipse.

I have tried lot of options, like enabling jpda port in tomcat and enabling debugger in eclipse, but i didn't get the expected result.

Could any one help me to achieve this?

Suresh.

Comment: Why jdpa is not working for you? Can you elaborate this a bit more?

Comment: When you start Tomcat server B, you could just run it with a debug configuration (i.e. start it with `Debug as...` instead of `Run as...`. Then you'll have the ability to add breakpoints and everything. Would that help?